# Multiple card expansion is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display multiple cards in a responsive grid view and when we click on a card it should expand and fill up the entire screen with its image and card-details and when we click again, it should go back to its grid view.

In the code link I have given below, it is working for one card , but when I input multiple cards, it's not working.

How can I fix the code given here?

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card__cover">
                <div class="header-image">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="title-wrap">
                    <h1 class="article-title">Dark House</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="card__cover-exerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dolores facere, nostrum suscipit modi, necessitatibus nulla sequi, neque quidem vero. <br><br>
                    <span class="social">
                        <i class="fa fa-facecard"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card__content">
                <p><span class="drop-cap">O</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias est incidunt odit ea adipisci animi nihil voluptates iure beatae explicabo asperiores enim ex placeat itaque minus error temporibus voluptate corporis suscipit commodi voluptatibus praesentium molestiae, perspiciatis nulla. Accusantium harum nisi maiores, velit perferendis, nesciunt ad, porro sequi aliquid maxime molestias!</p>
                
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nobis fuga delectus tempore. Odio ipsa voluptate ex nobis ratione consequatur dignissimos dolorum culpa, ipsam sit dolorem itaque excepturi, natus sed deleniti incidunt ipsum asperiores! Molestiae cumque quam nulla, nam inventore. Necessitatibus blanditiis cumque laboriosam, id, ad unde quo ipsum nulla.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum accusantium velit expedita, minima sapiente unde magnam dicta. Consequuntur cumque numquam sed deserunt, quidem officia illo blanditiis ipsum, commodi distinctio quam molestias dolore, doloremque corporis? Rem ad recusandae delectus accusamus, harum quisquam perferendis dolor aut consectetur nesciunt atque laborum ab dolores.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, neque, magnam. Impedit deleniti ad alias, unde vero quis mollitia, tenetur minima porro, officia iusto quae harum labore nostrum aliquid aut maxime, architecto in reprehenderit. Doloribus pariatur quam fuga sed modi veniam, vel corporis magnam quis eius cumque voluptate, dolore repellendus labore nobis, voluptatibus dicta sapiente doloremque! Enim dicta totam debitis cumque similique, natus, consequatur quidem cum incidunt, sint quos. Ea.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident voluptatum possimus dolores nesciunt natus quaerat quas quo quam obcaecati ducimus totam quia sint, et nobis nisi tenetur id aspernatur quibusdam molestiae reprehenderit sed incidunt. Voluptas error necessitatibus sed inventore, quasi facilis, est. Asperiores atque laboriosam inventore quis eos nulla. Fuga neque odit maiores facilis voluptas nemo numquam, eos amet molestias.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="card">
            <div class="card__cover">
                <div class="header-image">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="title-wrap">
                    <h1 class="article-title">Dark House</h1>
                </div>
                <p class="card__cover-exerpt">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dolores facere, nostrum suscipit modi, necessitatibus nulla sequi, neque quidem vero. <br><br>
                    <span class="social">
                        <i class="fa fa-facecard"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card__content">
                <p><span class="drop-cap">O</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias est incidunt odit ea adipisci animi nihil voluptates iure beatae explicabo asperiores enim ex placeat itaque minus error temporibus voluptate corporis suscipit commodi voluptatibus praesentium molestiae, perspiciatis nulla. Accusantium harum nisi maiores, velit perferendis, nesciunt ad, porro sequi aliquid maxime molestias!</p>
                
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab nobis fuga delectus tempore. Odio ipsa voluptate ex nobis ratione consequatur dignissimos dolorum culpa, ipsam sit dolorem itaque excepturi, natus sed deleniti incidunt ipsum asperiores! Molestiae cumque quam nulla, nam inventore. Necessitatibus blanditiis cumque laboriosam, id, ad unde quo ipsum nulla.
                </p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum accusantium velit expedita, minima sapiente unde magnam dicta. Consequuntur cumque numquam sed deserunt, quidem officia illo blanditiis ipsum, commodi distinctio quam molestias dolore, doloremque corporis? Rem ad recusandae delectus accusamus, harum quisquam perferendis dolor aut consectetur nesciunt atque laborum ab dolores.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad, neque, magnam. Impedit deleniti ad alias, unde vero quis mollitia, tenetur minima porro, officia iusto quae harum labore nostrum aliquid aut maxime, architecto in reprehenderit. Doloribus pariatur quam fuga sed modi veniam, vel corporis magnam quis eius cumque voluptate, dolore repellendus labore nobis, voluptatibus dicta sapiente doloremque! Enim dicta totam debitis cumque similique, natus, consequatur quidem cum incidunt, sint quos. Ea.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident voluptatum possimus dolores nesciunt natus quaerat quas quo quam obcaecati ducimus totam quia sint, et nobis nisi tenetur id aspernatur quibusdam molestiae reprehenderit sed incidunt. Voluptas error necessitatibus sed inventore, quasi facilis, est. Asperiores atque laboriosam inventore quis eos nulla. Fuga neque odit maiores facilis voluptas nemo numquam, eos amet molestias.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        $('.card').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('card--expanded');
        });
    </script>
```

https://codepen.io/Avatar_73/pen/NWrbpdd

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In that article, pay particular attention to the second bullet in the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem", where it says "**also copy the code into the question itself**." (emphasis in the original).

Comment: It looks like you found a way to disguise the Codepen link so that the editor would not require you to add code. Please don't do that - it means that when someone edits the question, they then have to do that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By not working, I'm going to assume that you mean that, in the Codepen, when you add multiple cards and click on one, it doesn't fill the page.

This is because you're using `flexbox` but you're trying to play with `width` in the traditional way. For instance, you're setting a 400px width on the card elements, but the way you're using `flexbox` on the container element, `flexbox` automatically governs the width of these elements when you have multiple elements of this class and where that 400px width would cause the elements to wrap/overflow. So `width` acts like a maximum width for when there's space, and is ignored when there isn't.

All I added to the Codepen was this:

```
.card--expanded {
  height: 100%;
  /* width: 100%; <- this isn't needed */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 100% 0 0; /* <-- new code */
}
```

and an individual card should expand to the desired full width.

If you're making a responsive grid you will want to look into this further, however, so that your cards will wrap as you want them to and you will need to look further into `flex:`, `flex-wrap` and other `flexbox` properties.

Comment: Thanks you so much , it solved the problem. Can you refer to anything where I can learn more about flexbox properties?

Comment: You're very welcome! Sure try these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax

Comment: Hey, I tried adding flex properties to the wrapper class, but nothing seems to work.Can you please help out?

Comment: The best thing would be to implement a grid system. This will give you more straightforward control over your layout. A good example of an existing grid system that uses `flexbox` is Google's [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io). [Jump to this section on layout](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section) to see their grid system and use your browser's Inspector/dev tools to reverse engineer the CSS properties and media queries used. They also have [templates](https://getmdl.io/templates/index.html) you can reverse engineer in a similar way.

Comment: Being Material Design, it already has card component styling that you could easily tweak to suit your needs.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in the js, sorry I don't know jQuery but I did it with vanilla js

```
const container = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
for(let i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
  const children = container.children[i];
  children.addEventListener('click', function() {
    children.className = children.className === 'card' ? 'card--expanded' : 'card';
  });
}
```

If you only catch a single div, the event will be on a single div. But if you capture the container of those divs, you can add the event to each children div in a for